# Close reason for 'blatantly off topic' / 'philosophical problem unclear'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

We're getting quite some questions that are closed with a custom close reason. Over the past 90 days, we closed 234 questions, 40 (17%) with a custom reason. Looking through the list of custom close reasons that have been used over these past 90 days, I see many of the form

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the philosophical problem is unclear.

or

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about philosophy.

Also in my experience, we're getting quite some questions that are just 'blatantly off topic'. Examples include

- "What does this quote mean?"
- Strictly mathematical questions
- Questions about English usage (even when texts occur in a philosophical context)

**I think we could benefit for a new close reason** to cover these kinds of situations. I'm not sure (yet) how to formulate it, but something like

> While this question may be related to philosophy or occur in a philosophical context, the question itself doesn't seem to be about philosophy, and is therefore not a good fit for our site.

Do you also think we could benefit from this, and if there is support from the community, could such a close reason be added? Suggestions for textual changes / scope broadening/narrowing are of course most appreciated.

---

**Note**: question close stats may be found for 2k+ users at https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last90days.

**Note**: [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com) has a close reason 'blatantly off topic - this question has nothing to do with cryptography'.

Comment: Some other sites have a reason that (when ported here) would sound like `This question is not about philosophy, within the scope defined in the help center.`

Comment: @mixedmath I believe that's what written when we used a custom close reason; see e.g. http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/24664/2953

Comment: yes. I meant to say that some other sites have that as an entire option with no additional commentary added. Sorry

Comment: @mixedmath oh, I didn't see that before, but that certainly would be an idea too. Often we don't get a response from the OP, so we don't need to spend a lot of time writing a good reason every time again.

Comment: I wish this was a *standard* close reason across stacks. I must imagine it was at some point, and was removed for some reason after a meta discussion. But I'm too lazy^W busy to research on Meta.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the same problem several months ago and added a generic off-topic close reason (esp. because the default one automatically attempts to migrate the question to another site). However, it needs another moderator to approve it and I believe at the time I was unable to get the attention of the other mods so it fell by the wayside.

We can definitely spice up the wording a bit and get this done one way or the other. :)

[image: need another moderator to approve]

Comment: I've remedied that. I'm sorry I didn't see it there.

Comment: I changed the wording to match what Keelan suggested above. Needs re-approval. Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, it's done!

Comment: Blazing fast! :D

Comment: Great, thanks a lot stoicfury & @virmaior!